# Can existing bcrypt hashes be manually inserted into a devise model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am currently porting a PHP application with an established user-base to Ruby on Rails.  The Rails application is using `Devise` for user authentication, and the existing PHP application is using `bcrypt` to hash and salt the passwords.  To my knowledge, the hashes are compatible with Devise.  As such, I assumed that I could manually assign an existing hash to the `encrypted_password` field of my User model in the following manner:

```
User.create!([
    {
         first_name: 'Jim', 
         last_name: 'Bob', 
         encrypted_password: '$2y$10$...', 
         email: 'abc@xyz.com'
    },
    ...
])
```

However, this produces the following error when I try to seed the database with `rake db:seed`: 
`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password can't be blank`

Is there a way to manually set the `encrypted_password` field of a devise model, short of resorting to raw SQL statements?  I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been doing exactly same thing few days ago. I've done something like this to import legacy users:

```
user = User.initialize
user.assign_attributes(encrypted_password: old_encrypted_password, password_salt: old_salt)
user.save!(validate: false)
```

Worked flawlessly - just make sure your user is valid, you can check that after save.

Comment: Using `assign_attributes` with `validation: false` worked.  It looks like I also had to swap out the `$2y` prefix with `$2a` to get comparisons working.